# Teleport to spawn in Minecraft creative mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When in Minecraft creative mode, there are times when I need to return to the spawn point. Are there any commands (in vanilla Minecraft) that you can use to quickly teleport back to spawn?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you have cheats enabled in the world then you can use the command `/kill` to respawn at the spawn point. You can use the command `/gamerule keepInventory true` to avoid losing items on death.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid losing inventory when using that command in creative mode? (I'd prefer to go back to spawn without losing my entire inventory.)

Comment: Probably not, alternately if you know the <x,y,z> coordinates of the spawn you can use the `/tp PLAYER x y z` command to teleport the named player to the x,y,z location specified. This will keep your inventory.

Comment: I once played a vanilla Minecraft map called "Herobrine's Mansion" that kept the player's items on death, so there must be some way to keep items on death in vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: If you use the command `/gamerule keepInventory true` then you will keep your inventory on death in the current map.

Comment: In that case, why do you think it's not possible to avoid losing the inventory when using `/kill`?

Comment: Sorry, that was due to my insufficient research on gamerules, I retract my former statement of non-possibility.

Answer (score 7):

You need to have cheats on for this to work. If you use the command `/gamerule keepInventory true` before using `/kill` you will die and respawn at your spawn point with all your inventory. I've done it, so I can confirm it works.

Comment: The order of this response would have saved me the headache of my lost inventory arrangement. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always just dig straight down until you hid the void below bedrock, and that should kill you and respawn you.  It will be a short trip down on creative.  Still doesn't save your inventory, but its another solution

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the `/kill` command, along with `/gamerule keepInventory true`? That would keep your inventory and teleport you back to spawn, without doing any damage to the map.

Comment: If you don't have cheats enabled, you might not be able to use the /kill command, nor the /gamerule command.